# Geocoder always return some results

Tags: javascript, geocoder

I'm using Geocoder for my app and it works just fine, except one thing - it ALWAYS return results even for non-existing address and always the same results.
So if i'm sending some "asfasdfsdgsdg" - it gets me a results somewhere in KANSAS and i need no results instead.

```
            this.geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequestParams, (results, status) => {
            if ((status === 'OK') && results && results[0]) {
                this.searchStoresByCoordinates(
                    {
                        //These are always the same for random search phrase like "dsafsdagasgasgasg"
                        latitude: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                        longitude: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
                    },
                    //This one becomes United States
                    results[0].formatted_address
                );
            } else {
                //Need to be here
            }
        });
```

Request params:

```
    const geocoderRequestParams = {
        address: "sdfdgdfhdfhsdh",
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: "US"
        }
    };
```

Comment: It's defaulting to the geographic center of the US-48? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_center_of_the_United_States#Contiguous_United_States

Comment: Could you please add some code examples? Is it similar to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019972/geocoder-using-random-latitude-and-longitude-instead-of-passed-values

Comment: added to the question

Comment: What's the response for that request? If you provide the response we can wrap a condition around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Just added handling for

```
results[0].formatted_address !== 'United States'
```